# Sonar Typescript not linting

Tags: typescript, sonarqube, tslint

I installed the Pablissimo/SonarTsPlugin as instructed on the read me and even though it pulls in all the typescript files

[image]

and seems to recognize the linting profile

[image]

none of the files seems to have linting (I really dought my code is perfect),
I have checked the logs and there are no errors, I can even see the command that runs tslint without issues, not sure what I need to do to start getting linting on my typescript files

Comment: The typescript plugin of sonarqube only run a tslint check with the rules you give. This will not check the code like the javascript plugin. For example: `console.log` will not raise a warning/error in typescript, but in javascript there will be one.

Comment: @Brainjump thanks for this how do I set the rules for it to check

Comment: You need a tslint.json file that will contain the rules look at this [doc](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/tslint-json/) for futher information. Then you can set the path of the file inside the sonar-project.properties with this line:
`sonar.ts.tslint.configPath=/path/to/the/tslint.json`